# JS. knockback.js

Tags: ajax, javascript

собсна кто использовал? поделитесь опытом пожалуйста, кто говорит "слишком сыро", кто "да хоть сейчас в продакшн".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ИМХО попытка смешивать 2 абсолютно противоположных подхода к построению js-приложений обречена на провал, `backbone` и `knockout` предназначены для решения разных задач и использовать их вместе не имеет смысла

Comment: не спорю, идеологически это может и не верно, но больно уж вкусно :)

Comment: declarative bindings для Backbone.View написать не так уж сложно, и тянуть для этого весь knockout нет необходимости, таже ситуация и с роутами и синхронизацией с сервером для Knockout

Comment: все, вы меня переубедили, согласен, не нужно вестись на вкусняшки.

Comment: да да, можно обойтись биндингами, я дурак